# wpf setup doesnt work in other computer

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-2008, installation

I have got setup project working with database and wpf on my machine, but when I try to install on other machine I can successfully install and run. When I try to run any function with datagrid just stops working but Can see is adding this to database, but on my machine with the setup runnig doesnt do that, displays without any problem. Havent got any idea of what can be.
pls helpppppp .

Answer (score 0):

I think, that problem is in references: maybe on your development pc is installed some control which is used in your project. So when you try to run on other pc, where application can't find right dll in GAC, you get exception. Try to read exception carefully and you will find information about what is missing (some exception details can get to event log of pc).

EDIT
Other possibility is connection string in config file.

Comment: Hi VikiciaR, Thank you for yor reply, I think its beacuse of datalinq which is generated with wpf, because I can see its adding my machine name, although I dont have my machine name on my connection string. Have u got any idea of how I can solve dat with wpf datalinq?